# how to split the below datas with reg exp?

Tags: python, split, expression, series, python-re

I have try so many times to split the below data into separate numbers and texts, but always failed.

```
0                '£22,000 per annum'
1      '£30,000 - £35,000 per annum'
2        '£250.00 - £350.00 per day'
3            '£250 - £280 per annum'
4      '£30,000 - £35,000 per annum'
```

is it possible to split the data into this format with one reg expression?

```
22000           per-annum
30000  35000    per-annum 
250     350     per-day
30000  35000    per-annum
```

Comment: the format should be  like in a dataframe

Comment: `I have try so many times`  Can you add the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pop value at those positions instead, especially since when they maintain set intervals. I don't know if the actual data holds the same format though. I'd push regular expression away as much as I can.

Comment: the colum's format is string , so i want to spearate figure and text, so that i can caculate numbers

Comment: You can iterate over the whole text stream and only store the numerical parts to some array perhaps. Basically during each iteration, you would want to NOT add " per" "annum" "day" "-" etc. You could iterate through characters on the spot for all the non-numeric positions, inside your first foor loop.